# Can we replace the Static application security testing SAST Tool like (Fortify, Checkmarx and IBM Appscan) with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, owasp, fortify, checkmarx

Can we replace the Static application security testing SAST Tool like (Fortify, Checkmarx and IBM Appscan) with SonarQube.

As per the SonarQube Roadmap Docs 8.1 (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/) says it covered all the security rules originated from establish standard: CWE, SANS Top 25, and OWASP Top 10.

Answer (score 2):

I this area no tool is the same. So when you run all those tools on the same code you will get some similar findings, some new one's and some missing (maybe false positives), depending how they implement the tool. Given the fact that SonarQube is relatively new in this field I would suggest using some other tool for this specific area also. Be aware that achieving a 100% detection result is extremely difficult/impossible.

Answer (score 0):

No you could definitively not actually. The coverage of Sonar is not the same thing you should view. You  must understood how they made the detections, the number os False Positive/Negative etc...

Fortify and Checkmarx do analysis of the flow inside your code. They could analyses the control you made before anything. Sonarqube is more rules based and not flow based.